# php explode like function in sql server 2005

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need to explode comma seperated string  for reporting purpose in mssql, what i exactly need is to convert string likr 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 as below

```
column
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I have been helpless so far now, its spoiling my weekend , help me out

Comment: it depends on the line endings...

Comment: [(facepalm)](http://bit.ly/KAHRkR)

Comment: oh, wait, nvm. I though you were converting the lines to a csv like thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below

```
DECLARE @str as nvarchar(4000) 
set @str=  'SELECT ' + replace( '1,2,3,4,5',',',' UNION SELECT ')
EXEC sp_executesql @str
```

Answer (score -2):

No you can't directly do this. You need to create function which returns the table accepting as string. You need create a table variable , add values to that and return.